# bash wait for open to finish

Tags: bash

I just asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830314/bash-using-a-file-name-as-input) and it made me think of another. Is is possible to get an exit code from whatever editor is opened from the bash command

```
open -t ...
```

It would be great if i could perform an action after the user had exited the text editor (and also work out if they saved the document while it was open). Is this possible?

Comment: Is this OS X? Or what OS/distribution?

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want the exit code, or just confirmation that the user has exited the text editor? The `-W` option causes `open` to wait until the editor exits before exiting itself. The value of $? would be, I suspect, the exit code of `open`, not the editor. Since the editor  likely is a child process of `launchd`, not your shell, I'm not sure how you retrieve the exit  code of the editor.

Comment: ok thanks for the help. I would like to know if the file has been saved b4 exiting but maybe to much to ask!